# New item in grid layout with user's parameters

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm trying to put component in grid layout with [this library](https://svelte-grid.vercel.app/). I need to finding new item of grid with new id and change "note-header" on what user writes in "header", I'm know what I need to do, but I don't know how I can made it with code. I'm think problem in "matchingObject" variable i'm surely don't know how to get value of id what I pushing in "itemsFromJS" array. Thanks in advance!
Code:

```js
export function NoteCreation() {
    const id = () => "_" + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
    const wide_note_container = document.getElementById('wide-note-container');
    const wide_note_header = document.getElementById('header');
    const wide_note_details = document.getElementById('details');
    const overlay_content = document.getElementById('overlay-container');
    const note_container = document.getElementById('note-container');
    const note_header = document.getElementById('note-header');
    const notes_div = document.getElementById('notes');
    overlay_content.style.transform = 'scale(0)';
    overlay_content.style.transition = 'transform 0.5s ease';
    wide_note_container.style.transform = 'scale(0)';
    wide_note_container.style.transition = 'transform 0.5s ease';
    notes_div.style.filter = 'none';
    invisible = true;
    let newNote = gridHelp.item({
        x: 2,
        y: 0,
        w: 1.7,
        h: 4,
    })
    let newId = id();
    itemsFromJS.push({ 6: newNote, id: newId});
    return newId;
    const matchingObject = itemsFromJS.find(newNote => newNote.id === newId);
    if (matchingObject) {
    note_header.textContent = wide_note_header.textContent;
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- Code of page -->
<script>
    import Grid from './Grid/src/index.svelte'; // Check if the path is correct
    import Note from './Note.svelte'; // Check if the path is correct
    import gridHelp from './Grid/src/utils/helper';
    import WideNote from './WideNote.svelte';
    import { NoteCreation, NoteCreationWindow, invisible, itemsFromJS} from './NotePageLogic'
    
    const breakpoint = 1200;
    const column = 6;
    const cols = [[breakpoint, column]];
    
    const id = () => "_" + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);

    let items = [
    {
      6: gridHelp.item({
        x: 2,
        y: 0,
        w: 1.7,
        h: 4,
      }),
      id: id(),
    },
  
    {
      6: gridHelp.item({
        x: 2,
        y: 0,
        w: 1.7,
        h: 4,
      }),
      id: id(),
    },
  ]
  
let combinedItems = [...items, ...itemsFromJS]
  
</script>


<Grid {cols} bind:items={combinedItems} let:item={item} rowHeight={100}>
  <!-- item is the current item from let:item -->
  {@const { x, y, w, h, component } = item} 
  <div id="notes" style="grid-column: {x + 1} / span {w}; grid-row: {y + 1} / span {h};">
    <Note />
  </div>
</Grid>

<div class="overlay-container" id="overlay-container">
  <div class="overlay-content visible" id="overlay-content">
    <WideNote />
  </div>
</div>

<style>  
  .overlay-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; /* Semi-transparent overlay */
    transform: scale(0); /* Initially set to zero size */
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  }

  .overlay-content {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    max-width: 80vw;
    max-height: 80vh;
     /* Add transition effect for scaling */
   
  }

</style>


<button on:click={NoteCreationWindow}>Create note</button>
```

Comment: First of all, you should not query or manipulate the DOM. Also, you have a return statement before other code which thus will never run.

Comment: On your advice, I removed "return newId;" and with the help of "console.log I made sure that "matchingObject" correctly finds an object, but instead of adding a new "gridHelp.item" object with a user-entered title, it changes the header "gridHelp.item" that already exists, from this you can understand that with my code I change the id of another "gridHelp.item" object. How can I fix this?

Comment: As I said, first of all fix your code. Do not query or manipulate the DOM, it makes a mess of things.